# Add Android In App Billing after publishing the app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I searched the web for an answer but I don't find any information about if I can add in app purchase after I publish the app in play store in a new update for the application or should I added it from the beginning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in app billing to an existing app and I've done so with a few of mine in the past.

A point to note is that you must upload an APK with billing permissions enabled at least into Alpha channel before you can test it.